# Holes between polygons after dissolve

Tags: qgis, shapefile, r, dissolve, holes

I’ve got a shapefile of Switzerland. Shown Polygons are 6-digit ZipCodes. Whenever I dissolve the file for example by 4-digit ZipCodes, it results in incorrect polygons.

[image]

Unfortunately some polygons borders aren't touching. If I zoom in on the orignal shapefile, it seems like there are empty spaces between the polygons.

[image: Gap between polygons]

I'm using QGIS and R and I've tried a lot.
This is my first time using GIS data.

Comment: There are processing tools for filling and deleting holes:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164296/how-to-fill-holes-in-polygons-automatically