# Polygons hull QGIS

Tags: qgis, tin, convex-hull, boundaries, delaunay

I'm currently working with old french cadastre on QGIS, I've vectorised it and now I want to tile it. I've georeferenced it, but it's not sufficient for a great result. To improve the result, I would like to create boundaries of my shape. Convex hull doesn't work as I want. I looking for a method who sticks at best at my shapes hull. I've tried TIN method, but it return some triangles out of boundaries and I've to delete them manually, and my job ask me to do it automatically. Dissolve method isn't sufficient too, because there are holes between polygons, and I want to take them in consideration. There is an image of the expected result. I can only use open-source software.

[image: Enveloppe]

Is there someone with a best idea?

Comment: Take a look here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164296/how-to-fill-holes-in-polygons-automatically

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I've tried solutions from this post, but I have roads wich are opened on the extent and I want to conserv them in the same time. This post fix my overlaps and holes between polygons. I'll see with my internship supervisor if TIN method is sufficient or not.

Comment: Among the solutions provided (linked by @Stefan), **Delete holes** tool preserves the road connected to outer ring of the polygon.