# Empty pixels in polygon border

Tags: qgis, vector, boundaries

I have a vector shape file with the basins of South Carolina. Some of the sub-basins polygons have a "hole" or no data pixel in their boundary (See photos for reference [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gosvI.png)) and I need them to be joined to the corresponding adjacent sub-basin. I've tried using *Delete Holes*, *v.clean* from grass, *Fix Geometries* without any luck. I'm using QGIS 3.14.

I also thought about rasterizing the layer, but the problem is that I will also attribute a value to all the ND values that are outside the state. I could do it by hand but this would take forever, wanted to find a more efficient way.

[image: All polygons basins]

[image: Close-up]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164296/filling-holes-in-polygons-automatically-using-qgis

Comment: Filling holes (actually removing holes) would be easy but probably you have gaps. The referenced answer seems to show good solutions.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at the link.