# GRASS tools (v.generalize, v. clean) error with polygons in projected CRS (EPSG:3857/Web Mercator)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grass-gis

I have troubles using several GRASS GIS tools from QGIS 3.16 (win 10) - I encountered the same problem [applying v.clean](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379309/error-while-removing-gaps-with-v-clean-in-qgis) as well as [v.generalize](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.generalize.html) tools (I tried Douglas Peuker algorithm). I tried a lot of different values for parameters. I always got an error and no output:

> ERROR 1: osgeo::proj::io::WKTParser::Private::buildEllipsoid: non
> double value
>
> ERROR: Unable to create OGR spatial reference

When reprojecting these polygon layers to EPSG:4326, the GRASS tools run without problem. I can set different values for the parameters (like threshold from 0.0001 to 1000), all work fine.

Why do I get errors when using the same tool/algorithm with the same layer in projected CRS?

Comment: Distance calculations is Web Mercator are *always* wrong, so it is particularly unsuited for generalization algorithms. Geographic coordinate systems are also problematic, because Cartesian degrees are a less than useful comparison units as well. You really ought to use a PCS appropriate for distance calculation.

Comment: I'm aware that Web Mercator is not ideal for distance relecant proceedings. However, geographic CRS with degrees are much less suited for distance calculations than web mercator as a projected CRS with meters as units. However, it's exactely the geographic CRS that works perfectely.

Comment: Web Mercator is more than "not ideal", it's *always wrong*. Generalization in degrees works, but is *more* precise (less effective) the further you get from the poles. Web Mercator simply fails because distances approach infinity as you reach the poles.

Comment: @Vince I think this deserves an appropriate answer so other people can find it. Changing to WGS84 (4326) solved my problem..