# Align polygon boundaries with another boundary in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis

I am working on vegetation community classification for a project and using QGIS3. This is completed by collecting field-plot data and then using aerial imagery to delineate the approximate boundaries of these communities. One of the objectives is to map out where these communities are spatially.

One issue that I am facing is that some of the polygons created, do not line up with the other polygons. In some cases there are gaps and others there are overlaps. Not only is this not visually pleasing, it also creates complications when determining the vegetation cover (in %) of the area of study.

Is there a way to streamline this so I can automatically make the polygons line up with each other? I am aware of the snapping and editing vertices tool but this is time consuming and want to know if there are better ways to do this.

[image]

Comment: Have you see this [question and answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/164296/128665)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Trace tool from the Snapping toolbar. This will speed up the process. Rather than snapping to individual vertices you can snap the edge of a polygon to the edge of another polygon no meter how complex.
From the Snapping Toolbar choose the Enable Tracing button, snap to the first vertex then simply move the cursor around your object and the TRACE tool will automatically select the vertices between the start point and your current location. You may need to choose intermediate vertices for complex polygo

Answer (score 1):

Try [Snap geometries to layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissnapgeometries):

> Snaps the geometries in a layer. Snapping can be done either to the
> geometries from another layer, or to geometries within the same layer