# Fixing holes in the buffered polygon using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geometry, buffer, polygon-creation, holes

My script uses a buffer and dissolves to create polygons around my points. However, there are holes in between the points. I do not want to increase the distance because then it will also cover the unnecessary areas. Is there an option that covers the holes in my polygon? my script is below:

[image]

```py
from qgis import processing
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


inlayDir = iface.activeLayer()

buffer_dist = 0.8

polygon =  processing.runAndLoadResults("native:buffer",
              {'INPUT':inlayDir,
               'DISTANCE':buffer_dist,
               'SEGMENTS':2,
               'END_CAP_STYLE':0,
               'JOIN_STYLE':0,
               'MITER_LIMIT':2,
               'DISSOLVE':True,
               'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164296/filling-holes-in-polygons-using-qgis

Answer (score 5):

[Delete holes](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisdeleteholes):

> Takes a polygon layer and removes holes in polygons

Use buffer output as input:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

buffered = processing.run("native:buffer", 
    {'INPUT':layer,'DISTANCE':1300,'SEGMENTS':5,'END_CAP_STYLE':0,
    'JOIN_STYLE':0,'MITER_LIMIT':2,
    'DISSOLVE':True,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})["OUTPUT"]
    
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:deleteholes", 
    {'INPUT':buffered,'MIN_AREA':0,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

[image]

Comment: this works ! thank you very much

Comment: Nice! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Since QGIS 3.0 there is another option available by utilization of the [`removeInteriorRings()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#afc97580ed7289056bc58e1fb467314cb) method of the `QgsGeometry` class.

> Removes the interior rings from a (multi)polygon geometry.
>
> If the minimumAllowedArea parameter is specified then only rings
> smaller than this minimum area will be removed.

```py
from qgis import processing
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import edit, QgsGeometry, QgsProject

inlayDir = iface.activeLayer()

buffer_dist = 0.8

polygon = processing.run("native:buffer", {
            'INPUT': inlayDir,
            'DISTANCE': buffer_dist,
            'SEGMENTS': 2,
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'DISSOLVE': True,
            'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
            })['OUTPUT']

with edit(polygon):
    for feat in polygon.getFeatures():
        wkt_geom = feat.geometry().removeInteriorRings(minimumAllowedArea=-1).asWkt()
        geom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt_geom)
        polygon.changeGeometry(feat.id(), geom)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(polygon)
```