Removing lines within polygon in QGIS
In the image of a single layer (below), how would I delete the lines in the left-hand polygon?
Perhaps an eraser tool would be a good addition to QGIS.


Please have a look on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164296/filling-holes-in-polygons-using-qgis. Or you can change to Edit mode and remove unnecessary vertexes.

Grzegorz's link shows a lot of options, but his suggestion to just remove vertices is what I would do based on your image.  When you select the polygon containing the slivers their vertices will all be selected.  With the vertex tool you can draw rectangles that will encompass most of these vertices which will show as circles and delete them.    Repeat with the few that remain taking care not to remove vertices in the outer poly.
